# Spring MockMvc integration test configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-test, mockmvc

Spring MockMvc integration test not working and failing with errors like

1) When @ContextConfiguration( classes = { WebMvcConfig.class } ) getting error like 
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
.... ClassNotFoundException: javax.el.ELManager

 
2) Tried changing to @ContextConfiguration( classes = { AppInitializer.class } ) getting error like  noHandlerFound WARNING: No mapping for request

 
The application is working fine , but the integration test is not working
The test doesn't need a servlet container as we are not parsing response.

1) Test class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration( classes = { AppInitializer.class } ) 
public class ItemControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void findById() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(view().name("editItems"));
    }

}
```

2) Configuration class

```
public class AppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
   @Override
   protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
      return new Class[] {  };
   }

   @Override
   protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
      return new Class[] { WebMvcConfig.class };
   }

   @Override
   protected String[] getServletMappings() {
      return new String[] { "/" };
   }
}
```

3) Spring MVC configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.inventory"})
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

   @Bean
   public InternalResourceViewResolver resolver() {
      InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
      resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
      resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
      resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
      return resolver;
   }

   @Bean
   public MessageSource messageSource() {
      ResourceBundleMessageSource source = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
      source.setBasename("messages");
      return source;
   }

   @Override
   public Validator getValidator() {
      LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
      validator.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
      return validator;
   }
}
```

4) Controller class

```
@Controller
public class ItemController {

    @Autowired
    private ItemService itemService;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String itemEntryForm(Locale locale, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("items", itemService.list());
        return "editItems";
    }

    @ModelAttribute("item")
    public Item formBackingObject() {
        return new Item();
    }

}
```

5) Error stacktrace

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:123)
        at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)
        at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:244)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' defined in org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcValidator' defined in org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.validation.Validator]: Factory method 'mvcValidator' threw exception; nested exception is javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000183: Unable to initialize 'javax.el.ExpressionFactory'. Check that you have the EL dependencies on the classpath, or use ParameterMessageInterpolator instead
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:787)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:528)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
        at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:129)
        at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:61)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:275)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:243)
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
        ... 31 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcValidator' defined in org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.validation.Validator]: Factory method 'mvcValidator' threw exception; nested exception is javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000183: Unable to initialize 'javax.el.ExpressionFactory'. Check that you have the EL dependencies on the classpath, or use ParameterMessageInterpolator instead
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:645)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:475)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:874)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:778)
        ... 49 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.validation.Validator]: Factory method 'mvcValidator' threw exception; nested exception is javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000183: Unable to initialize 'javax.el.ExpressionFactory'. Check that you have the EL dependencies on the classpath, or use ParameterMessageInterpolator instead
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:640)
        ... 63 more
    Caused by: javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000183: Unable to initialize 'javax.el.ExpressionFactory'. Check that you have the EL dependencies on the classpath, or use ParameterMessageInterpolator instead
        at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.buildExpressionFactory(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:116)
        at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.<init>(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:47)
        at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean$HibernateValidatorDelegate.buildMessageInterpolator(LocalValidatorFactoryBean.java:437)
        at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean.setValidationMessageSource(LocalValidatorFactoryBean.java:169)
        at com.inventory.config.WebMvcConfig.getValidator(WebMvcConfig.java:39)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerComposite.getValidator(WebMvcConfigurerComposite.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.getValidator(DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.java:139)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.mvcValidator(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:709)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
        ... 64 more
```

Comment: You're missing `javax.el-api` dependency from your test classpath?

Comment: @Kayaman it does not solve the issue ,Is its needed by tomcat? And i think for test we dont need tomcat

Comment: No, for test you need `javax.el-api` since you don't have anything else that would provide that class. The stacktrace is pretty clear about what's missing, so unless you provide the `javax.el.ELManager` class, you're going to be staring at that stacktrace for a long time.